# ALB controller path based routing

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, routes, path, config

I have this ingress resource and I want to access my service via another path (**"/myapp"** for example)   instead of the original path **"/"**

```
- apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    annotations:
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: group-0
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "443"
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: 200,302
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
      kubernetes.io/ingress.access: public
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    - group.ingress.k8s.aws/group-0
    generation: 3
    name: myapp-ingress
  spec:
    rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - backend:
            service:
              name: svc-app
              port:
                number: 7443
          path: /myapp
          pathType: Prefix
```

when I access the host **"example.com/myapp"** I get 404 error page.

I want to be able to access the service via the path **example.com/myapp**

Comment: 404 indicates the call made it to your service.